# Howto convert file to byte stream in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to convert a file to a byte array.

another way round of below one

```
let file = new File([myBlob], "name");
```

file need to convert into a byte stream

Comment: Do you work with image or not?
Please provide the code you have already tried

Comment: Try this let byteArray = new Uint8Array(file)

Answer (score 3):

You can probably try to use FileReader API available in Browser.

```
let file = new File(...) // this could be from file input or other source
let fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
fileReader.onload = function(ev) {
    const result = ev.target.result;
    console.log(result); // here it is
}
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47069615/5075755), if the result from `readAsArrayBuffer` will not work for you, you may need to convert it to the real `byte[]` using `new Uint8Array`. Here is extended version of the above code:

```
let file = new File(...) // this could be from file input or other source
let fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
fileReader.onload = function(ev) {
    const array = new Uint8Array(ev.target.result);
    const fileByteArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       fileByteArray.push(array[i]);
    }
    console.log(array); // here it is
}
```

And here is implementation wrapped in promise for comfortable usage:

```
function getByteArray(file) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
       fileReader.onload = function(ev) {
           const array = new Uint8Array(ev.target.result);
           const fileByteArray = [];
           for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
               fileByteArray.push(array[i]);
           }
           resolve(array);  // successful
       }
       fileReader.onerror = reject; // call reject if error
   })
}

//usage
let file = new File(...)
getByteArray(file).then((byteArray) => {
    // do whatever you need
    console.log(byteArray);
})
```

P.S.
If for some reason you can not refer to `ev.target`, please try to use `fileReader.result` instead.

Comment: this line show error. const result = ev.target.result; result is not property of target

Comment: It should work as event.target is documented in the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload

Comment: @SSSS see my updated answer. Try to use fileReader.result

Comment: @SSSS, so did the `fileReader.result` solve the issue? 
P.S.
if this answer solved your task, please, mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. sure i do now.one last thing then how can I convert this byte array to string ??

Comment: @SSSS, that is a separate question. Please, check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195865/converting-byte-array-to-string-in-javascript