# crop image and get the cropped image part data as string in php

Tags: php, image

I am trying to get a image data from url using `file_get_contents()` and then crop the image and pass the the cropped image data as string to another function.
My codes are,

```
 $imageData = file_get_contents($imageurl);
$imgcrop = imagecrop($x,$y,$width,$height);

gettype($imgcrop ) // a resource type, I want them to be string/bytes

uploadThisData(imgcrop) ;
```

So my problem is `$imgcrop` data is resource type, how can I get string/bytes value from this? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert input=file to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37134433/convert-input-file-to-byte-array)

Answer (score 1):

You can save your image resource as a png by doing `imagepng($imgcrop,'cropped.png')`

You can then convert the png into a byte array like this

```
imagepng($imgcrop,'cropped.png');
$cropedpng = imagecreatefrompng("cropped.png");
$array = array(); 

foreach(str_split($cropedpng) as $char){ 
    array_push($array, ord($char)); 
}
var_dump(implode(' ', $array));
```

Or you could convert it into Base64 like this

```
imagepng($imgcrop,'cropped.png');
$cropedpng = imagecreatefrompng("cropped.png");
$base64 = ''. base64_encode($cropedpng).'';
```