# How to convert image to byte array using js

Tags: javascript, base64, byte

I am trying to convert `image` to `byte array` using only javascript and send to api. I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9273250/11866037) but it only shows to convert to base64 then send it to server side. Are there any other ways to convert to byte array using js or I can't just send byte array to api ?

Comment: If you are just wanting to convert a file that you've uploaded into a byte array, you might be able to use the solution to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37134433/convert-input-file-to-byte-array

Comment: This all depends on how you're getting your input. Most of the time, you want a Uint8Array or ArrayBuffer to efficiently send your data to the API, but to get that you will need either FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer (if from a user upload) or CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData().data. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData.