# How to send a user-supplied audio file in smaller audio slices to be processed on the server in js

Tags: javascript, audio

I have a need to receive audio from the user, and it can be very long in duration, so I was wondering if there is a way to slice this audio into smaller pieces of for example 5 seconds, and send those slices to the server. I searched a lot and what I found was to send the data stream from the microphone to a server, not a complete audio provided by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can load the file into a byte array on the client side, which makes it easy to divide up. Then reassemble the parts on the server side.

It looks like there are multiple suggestions as to how to read a file into a byte buffer at this earlier [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37134433/convert-input-file-to-byte-array) question.